# z3py: Can the switch of the orders of constraints affect the performance of the Z3 SMT solver?

Tags: performance, z3, smt, z3py

I am trying to improve the performance of my z3py code for making an inference. Do you think changing the sequence that the logic constraint being added to the solver might possibly help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may, but switching solvers or building a specialized tactic will probably have a greater influence.

Comment: Thanks. Are you aware of any good tutorials explaining what solver to choose and how to write a customized tactic? I tried hard to search but failed.

Comment: From Z3Py, you can print the set of available tactics. Then you may want to compose then in some way (using AndThen() for example).
useful functions in Z3Py:
tactics() - returns list of tactics;
tactic_description(name);
 describe_tactics() - combines the other 2 functions